# Hosting password compromised

Tags: authentication, passwords, password-management, web-hosting

Last Monday I received two emails from my hoster:

- 10h42: Connection notification
- 10h42: Confirm your notification

I didn't login that day, so I knew something was wrong. I immediately logged in, changed the password and activated 2FA.

I called the support and they told me that indeed there was a "successful" login but they detected it as suspicious that why the second email was sent. It contained a verification code to be able to continue. (the attacker was prompted to enter this code)

So, at this point, someone had my login and password for this website. Hopefully it was blocked. It was an old password I didn't changed since quite a long time (yes I am guilty for this). But I am wondering where it was compromised and how.

I am using a password manager since five years now.

I checked https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords and this password is not compromised. So I don't understand what happened. I have the [IP](https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/37.166.209.240) that was used for the login.

How could I understand what happened? Do I need to fill a complaint?
Thanks for your help.

**Edit**:

- The password had 12 characters with numbers, lowercase, uppercase and symbols
- It wasn't used on other websites.
- Originally this password was the original password of a server I had with this hoster.

Comment: Your question does not provide any information of where you might have used the same password  or who did know the password and thus where it might have been leaked. It is also unknown how complex the password was, i.e. if it could have been guessed. Therefore we cannot explain how this can happened and if you might need to file a complaint and against whom. Also  `haveibeenwned` is only a collection of well-known leaks and not all possible leaks.

Comment: _"But I am wondering where it was compromised and how"_ is hopelessly broad. It's like asking us "How did a burglar get the key to my house". We have no idea... _But_ if you have a password manager and use different passwords for every site, and change them (all) at some regular interval, you're probably as safe as you can be.

Comment: Details added. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Possibilities: You reuse your password on other sites and one of those sites was compromised and this compromise was not disclosed. You wrote down your password and lost that note. It is easy to guess. You shared it with someone who then compromised it.... I am sure there are many more scenarios but what we are doing here is just guessing because there is only 1 actual way to know and that is if the attacker tells you where they got the password from.

Comment: You can't "understand what happened". There are simply too many ways for a password to be exposed.

Comment: I understand but I wanted to ask. Is the IP useless? I seems to come from my country and town.

Comment: Did you  use the password anywhere else?

Comment: Not the same, but I had a pattern with a different suffix.

Comment: That IP is a mobile IP ... Did you log in on your phone?

Comment: No, (free mobile) it's not my phone provider.

Comment: The password is too complex to brute force and you didn't use it anywhere else. From what source is the password accessible in plain-text, and what route was there to access it? Nobody can answer that better than yourself. Otherwise, the only explanation is a severe security vulnerability on your provider's side.

Comment: Thanks for the help. If someone can transform the comments in an answer so I can accept it.